# How to layout a simple, aligned form using Kendo UI Web

Tags: html, css, kendo-ui

Just getting into Kendo UI Web, and trying to figure out the best way to layout a simple form.  Frankly put, I'm a little shocked at the lack of documentation for performing such a basic task.  I am using the kendo.bootstrap theme and trying to figure out how to organize a simple form where the labels are in one column, and the associated inputs are in another column, both being properly aligned etc.

If you follow the docs for creating a simple form, with textbox controls and labels, the text box controls do not align properly...even on their examples.

Using the following code to demonstrate this:

```
<div>
<ul class="forms">
    <li>
        <label class="k-label">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" class="k-textbox" />         
    </li>
    <li>
        <label class="k-label">Password:</label>
        <input type="text" class="k-textbox" />         
    </li>
</ul>
```

Not sure if the k-label was needed, saw it and thought I'd try it...doesn't help tho.

I looked over all the styling documentation and I don't see anything there that helps with creating a simple but styled form.  Does Kendo UI Web provide any fixed or fluid grid system to help layout forms, or is the user responsible for this?  Thx...

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, Kendo does not provide anything for form layout (however Kendo Mobile does). That would be up to the user. Generally it is a simple as providing a CSS fixed width for your labels, as seen [here](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/validator/index.html).

```
            .k-textbox {
                width: 11.8em;
            }

            label {
                display: inline-block;
                width: 90px;
                text-align: right;
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Kendo does provide this. You just have to use the classes editor-label and editor-field in kendo.common.min.css

Example:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Description, new { style="width:500px;" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
</div>
```

Comment: Same.  This doesn't seem to be a stylized at all.

Comment: You must have some other CSS conflicting. Double check in a browser inspection on the element in question.

Kendo UI v2016.1.420 shows the classes defined as:

.k-edit-form-container .editor-label {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  width: 30%;
  padding: .4em 0 1em;
  margin-left: 2%;
  text-align: right;
}
.k-edit-field,
.k-edit-form-container .editor-field {
  float: right;
  clear: right;
  width: 60%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  padding: 0 0 .6em;
}

Comment: For instance, if the width of your editor is greater than the container you are trying to put it in it will render on the next line or below the label.